# Symfony - Doctrine Annotations default value for a foreign key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

We have two entities with a ManyToOne cardinal relationship.
The Article entity has three kinds of status. This status was recorded on ArticleStatus table.

ArticleStatus table content:

id | status

1 - Pending

2 - Approved

3 - Denied

**Entity/Article.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ArticleRepository::class)
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $article_name;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=ArticleStatus::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $status;

    ...

    public function getStatus(): ?ArticleStatus
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(?ArticleStatus $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Entity/ArticleStatus.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ArticleStatusRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ArticleStatusRepository::class)
 */
class ArticleStatus
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $status;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(string $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Every new article needs to be created with Pending status. How can I set up value 1 to status_id foreign key by default using Doctrine Annotations?

Comment: So, instead of having a column "status", which is essentially an enum, you opted to make it a full fledged entity. My advice would be to make it a simple value, not an entity. Or do you actually have a good reason to do this?

Comment: @Jakumi if you decide to add a new status, or remove one, or rename one you would have to go through every place in your code where it's used and modify it to allocate for the change.

Comment: @MartinM. if "status" was replaced with "tag", I would probably agree. However, in this particular case I strongly disagree. Looking at the provided entity and the way the problem description is phrased, I'm convinced status is business logic, and there are probably conditions in code tied to either id and/or name, which would make either adding or renaming (or both) weird anyhow and would require code changes. So either the status entities are bad or using entities in the first place is bad. Also it reads like there won't be more status (pl.). I would use constants.

Comment: @Jakumi Yes, if you are 100% sure there will not be any changes, constants would make it simpler. Adding or removing would make it necessary to change your business logic regardless. But if you have a list and want to show the status you would either have a switch that you'll need to modify (possibly on multiple places) or add a migration to change the values for all records. It's a little extra work, but it can be avoided and you don't lose that much performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In annotations it's not possible. There are a few different methods you can try, I suggest a pre-persist event.

Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304448/symfony2-set-default-value-in-entity-constructor)

Comment: Thank you, Martin!

I will resolve it using a default string value when the article is created. 
So, I don't need an entity ArticleStatus anymore. I will set the "Pending" string value inside the Article entity.